# Cannot read property 'then' of undefined AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have written a factory method as :

```
myApp.factory('GetUserCurrentLocationService', ['$q', function ($q) {
            var GetUserCurrentLocationService = {};
            GetUserCurrentLocationService.getLocation = function () {
                var def = $q.defer();
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                        def.resolve(position);
                        return def.promise;
                    });
                }
            }
            return GetUserCurrentLocationService;
        }
    ]);
```

and in controller I have written:

```
GetUserCurrentLocationService.getLocation().then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    },function(error){
        console.log(error);
    })
```

but whenever i am running this I am getting error  **Cannot read property 'then' of undefined AngularJS**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now your factory `getLocation` function returns *undefined*, it's not returning `Promise`, thus the error is expected. Basically you have misplaced the `return def.promise;` statement.

```
GetUserCurrentLocationService.getLocation = function () {
    var def = $q.defer();
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            def.resolve(position);
        });         
    } else {
        //Also reject if navigator.geolocation is undefined
        def.reject({});
    }
    //Function should return promised
    return def.promise;
}
```

Comment: `console.log(response);` is still not showing anything

Comment: @lakshay, Are you getting any data then `getCurrentPosition()`?

Comment: i don't think so..........suddenly the navigator method has stop working.......it was working before

Comment: is there anything I can do?